# Creating my own equals method for a linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

For my java class we need to write equals methods comparing two instances of the LinkedSet class that uses doubly linked lists using nodes. Thus far I have only really learned how to compare arrays so I am not too familiar with this concept and am really struggling with this assignment.

https://gist.github.com/rpcarney4/c50dd44d2728c266b26b621bebb12444
(here is a link to the code i currently have, the methods in question are on lines 170 and 185)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

edit: also what is the difference between the methods? in the parameters there is Set s and then LinkedSet s. Why do we need to have two different methods for this?

Comment: HINT: `a.equals(b)` if, for every element `e` in set `a`, it is true that `b.contains(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code Set is an interface while LinkedSet is a class implementing it.

Now since you already have implemented the intersection for this class, it is very easy to check equality using that between two LinkedSet instances. This is because your LinkedSet instance won’t allow duplicate values to be added in the LinkedSet. So, for testing equality between two LinkedSets, take their intersection and the check if the size of the intersection equals both the linkedsets size. If this condition is satisfied, both the LinkedSets are equal.